# using AssertJ usingComparatorForType method with inheritance

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, assertj

I found the assertj (3.5.2) method : usingComparatorForType and fall in love with it.

But I wanted to compare 2 XmlGregorianCalendar dates with an error margin. And this magic method doesn't worked for this case...

Here is why :

- XmlGregorianCalendar is an Abstract class
- The real object type is : XmlGregorianCalendarImpl
- This class (XmlGregorianCalendarImpl) is private, so I can't create a specific comparator for this class.

Do you have any solution for this case ? Is there another method which works fine with inheritance ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While the method doesn't seem to check for different applicable Comparators, just for exact matches, `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` is not `private`, it's `public` in Java 8. In other versions it might be `package` access, in which cases you still could access the class via reflection (`Class.forName(...)`) and create a comparator in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `usingComparatorForType` should support this use case : https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/758

Comment: Thanks for the submission !